# Drupal 8 : send a PDF file after form submit

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

Hello i'm using a Drupal 8, i would like to create a form and on submit it send a PDF file at the email in the form.

Comment: Do you want to generate PDF file on fly and use data collected with that form or just to send some existing PDF file from disk?

Comment: Hello, just send some existing PDF file that's all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use [the Rules module](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) if you don't want to do any coding.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way for creating webforms in drupal is by using Webform module:

https://www.drupal.org/project/webform

Use `hook_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id)` to add your custom submit handler to that form. Inside your hook function you should add code that looks something like this:

```
$form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'your_custom_handler_function_name';
```

Basically that `$form['actions']['submit']['#submit']` is a list of submit handler (an array) and you are just adding yours. It may be a bit different - you'll have to inspect and see exact structure. Don't forget to clear the cache after adding your function!

Then your custom submit handler will be called when form is submitted so inside your function you can send an email with PDF attached to it.

Your custom submit handler should look like this:

```
function your_custom_handler_function_name($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
...
```

For sending emails with attachments you'll have to install additional module, like Swift Mailer:

https://www.drupal.org/project/swiftmailer

or some similar.